# How to Create Metastore in Azure Databrick (pyspark)?

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-databricks

So I was following this doc : [Azure Databrick Unity Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/azure-managed-identities)

I followed every step until Use a managed identity to access storage managed by a Unity Catalog metastore which is titled in the doc.

When I go to the link of Azure Databrick console given in **Use a managed identity to access storage managed** by a Unity Catalog metastore section , I don't see any data section on the side navigation bar [I was following step 1 of Use a managed identity to access storage managed by a Unity Catalog metastore from the doc]

And if I go to Azure Databrick console from Azure portal, I have data section but after clicking it , I don't see any option to Create metastore .

So , how do I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you fulfill below Requirements:

•   You must be an Azure Databricks account admin.

•   Your Azure Databricks account must be on the Premium plan.

•   In your Azure tenant, you must have permission to create:

```
1. A storage account to use with Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2. See Create a storage account to use with Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2.

2. A new resource to hold a system-assigned managed identity. This requires that you be a Contributor or Owner of a resource group in any subscription in the tenant.
```

Also note

[image]

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/create-metastore

Comment: Thanks. I checked and mine is not a premium plan